# Sort the dataframe column value based on a priority list in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns as sted below:

```
Col 1       Col2
  A         RED
  B         GREEN
  C         AMBER
  D          RED
  E          GREEN
```

I want the output dataframe as:

```
Col1        Col2
 A           RED
 D           RED
 C           AMBER
 B            GREEN
 E            GREEN
```

I want the column to be sorted in the order of priorty red,amber and green
irrespective of column 1 value.

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 3):

Another solution :

```
  #create a mapping of the sort order
  sortbox = {'RED':1,'AMBER':2,'GREEN':3}

  #create new column with the sort order
  df['sort_column'] = df.Col2.map(sortbox)

  #sort with sort_column

 df.sort_values('sort_column').drop('sort_column',axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)


   Col 1    Col2
0   A       RED
1   D       RED
2   C       AMBER
3   B       GREEN
4   E       GREEN
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by adding another column which contains the second letter of each row in col2 and sort by it (that's the only sorting order I found suitable for your question):

```
d1 = {'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'col2': ['RED', 'GREEN', 'AMBER', 'RED', 'GREEN']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df1['col3'] = [i[1] for i in df1['col2']]
df1 = df1.sort_values(by='col3')
```

The result, after excluding 3rd column, is like the one you posted